# How do I moving the title of the biblography to the right side?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, hebrew

I'm writing document at Hebrew so it RTL, but my bibliography includes an English articles.

The result is this:
[image]

I want to move `מקורות` to the right side. Is it possible?

Here is the code:

```
\begin{english}
\addto\captionshebrew{\renewcommand{\refname}{\hebrewfont{מקורות}}} 
\renewcommand{\refname}{\hebrewfont{מקורות}}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}\nocite{*}
\bibliography{ref1}

\end{english}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide any [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) I'll propose a raw solution, more could be done knowing packages for bibliography you use.

Instad of

\renewcommand{\refname}{\hebrewfont{מקורות}}

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{\hebrewfont{מקורות}}
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}\nocite{*}
```

do

```
%...
\renewcommand{\refname}{}
\vskip\baselineskip%
\hspace{3cm}\minipage\textwidth%
    \section*{\hebrewfont{מקורות}}%
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\hebrewfont{מקורות}}\nocite{*}
\endminipage%
%...
```

Then you can adjust `hspace` for your own needings, also, possibly, you would want to change `\vskip\baselineskip` with `\vskip-\baselineskip` since *usually*, `\bibliography` command comes with a `\section*`, thus you maybe wat to remove that space.

If you don't want to find proper hspace to put a possible solution is with package `calc`, put in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{calc}
    \setlength{\myspace}{\textwidth-\widthof{\hebrewfont{מקורות}}}%
```

then use `\hspace{\myspace}` instead of `\hspace{3cm}` in the code above.

Comment: Not working :-\  it's just put it 3cm right, but it's not at right...

Comment: I'll update the answer with a way to add exactly the space you want.

Answer (score 0):

[The answer I found:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/647043/english-bibliography-in-hebrew-document-xetex/649164)
The `bidi` package provides the control sequence `\setLTRbibitems` precisely for this purpose. All you need to do is place this control word before inserting your bibliography.